# What does "Addresses are for individual bytes (8 bits)" mean?

Tags: c++, mips, cpu-architecture

Can someone explain this for me?

> Addresses are for individual bytes (8 bits)

I have pasted the entire paragraph below:

> The MIPS has a 32 bit architecture, with 32 bit instructions, a 32
>   bit data word, and 32 bit addresses.
>   It has 32 addressable internal registers requiring a 5 bit register address. Register 0 always has the the constant value 0.
>
> Addresses are for individual bytes (8 bits) but instructions must have
>   addresses which are a multiple of 4. This is usually stated as “instructions must be word aligned in memory.

Link to pdf:

http://web.cs.mun.ca/~paul/cs3725/material/review.pdf

In the code below, I don't understand `IMem[i] = bitset<8>(line)`

[image]

Comment: It means MIPS is byte-addressable, so 4-byte words have addresses 4 units away from each other.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode.  (And also for the reason Yakk described).  I was going to remove the C++ tag (which has nothing to do with most of the question), but the last line is a picture of some C++ code and a related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> explain this “Addresses are for individual bytes (8 bits)” for me?

It means that size of a byte is 8 bits. Two adjacent addresses will be 8 bits apart. A 32 bit word consists of 4 bytes.

Furthermore it means that - even though address operands of instructions must be aligned to a 4 byte boundary as explained in the following sentence - each byte has a unique address.

> By unique address, do you mean unique 5 bit values?

No. The *memory* addresses are 32 bit values.

> where are addresses usually saved?

Where-ever any values are saved. In the given description, two possible places have been described: In memory, or in a register.

Comment: By unique address, do you mean unique 5 bit values? Internal registers have a 5 bit register address right?

Comment: @Jake: you're talking about how machine code encodes register numbers inside an instruction.  Memory addresses are 32-bit values you can hold *in* a register.  Registers are a separate address space from memory, and you can't index them.  (e.g. you can't use a value in one register to select which other register you want to read.)  So register numbers aren't really addresses in that sense.  Only in CPU-architecture terms when we talk about an instruction-set as having "3 address" instructions like MIPS does.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer that I was looking for.
I have one more doubt tho, where are addresses usually saved?